# How to submit pyspark job in yarn cluster mode from code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can we submit a pyspark job in yarn cluster mode from Python code.

Comment: You can always just use the `subprocess` module to submit the job.

Comment: Without using spark-submit?

Comment: I think you'd still use `spark-submit`, but you're just calling it through the `subprocess` module. I'm not aware of a python API that wraps `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 1):

`spark-submit` is the command for submit the pyspark job on spark and we have to mention yarn cluster mode for deploy the job on cluster.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  py_files.py
```